# How can I aggregate a "Change in" variable to a total variable?

Tags: r, dataset, aggregate

I have a data set in R that looks like the following:

|Date | Paycheck |

---

|Jan 1st | 1,000|

---

|Jan 14 | |1,400|

---

(Sorry for the bad format). I want to create another column that is total yearly salary (so far). I've tried an aggregate function but I get a small data set of ~8 observations when my total data set is ~80. I already have my data broken down by "employee" essentially, so all I need to do is aggregate in my data set.

Thanks for any help.

What I want is:

|Date | Paycheck |Yearly salary to date |

---

|Jan 1st | 1,000 |1,000|

---

|Jan 14 | |1,400 |2,400|

Comment: I appreciate that you've apologised for the bad format, but rather, please just put it in a good format. You can review the guide on how to make a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). You can use `dput` to copy the structure of your data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `ave` in `base R` if we want to group by 'date' and create a new column

```
df1$new <- with(df1, ave(Paycheck, Date, FUN = cumsum))
```

---

If there is no groupinig

```
df1$new <- cumsum(df1$Paycheck)
```

Comment: Hi, I've converted this to a data frame and its just giving back a list of the paychecks. IE, its just the above dataset without the date which isn't really useful... How do I aggregate this so that the total yearly salary on the second paycheck is appropriately displayed as 2,400?

Comment: Hi, the first method adds another column (which is what I want) but basically just adds another paycheck column. The second one adds another column which is the total yearly salary which also doesn't work because I don't want the total salary but what they've been paid to date.

Comment: I have updated my question to show the table I want at the end. Hopefully this helps

Comment: Thank you very much this has answered the question and I have marked it.